# How to get the 2d dimensions of the object being drawn for hit test on canvas 2d after canvas transformations?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, canvas, webgl

I draw simple shapes on 2d canvas, while applying transformations on shapes like so:

```
  const rect = ({ x, y, width, height }) => {
    ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
    ctx.fillRect(x, y, width, height);
  };

  const transform = ({ translate, rotate, scale }, f) => {
    // ctx is a 2d canvas context
    ctx.save();

    if (translate) {
      ctx.translate(translate[0], translate[1]);
    }
    if (rotate) {
      ctx.rotate(rotate);
    }

    if (scale) {
      ctx.scale(scale[0], scale[1]);
    }

    f(ctx);

    ctx.restore();
  };
  const draw = () => {
     transform({ translate: [10, 10] }, () => {
        rect({ x: 0, y: 0, width: 10, height: 10 });
     });
  };
```

Now I need to know the dimensions of this rectangle in the canvas space so that I can hit test against the mouse click position.

Earlier I asked this question [How to get the 2d dimensions of the object being drawn for hit test on webgl after model view transform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57697719/how-to-get-the-2d-dimensions-of-the-object-being-drawn-for-hit-test-on-webgl-aft) about webgl hit test detection. But the solution doesn't apply here because I don't have a transformation matrix.

One possible solution is, I draw the same object on a different canvas called a collision canvas, with a specific color related to object, later when I want to hit test against a position on canvas, I query the collision canvas color on that position and see if the color matches the object specific color, would that be a good idea?

I see best solution is to use `ctx.currentTransform` method. Per the object's dimensions are known, the transformed dimensions can be found by this function:

```
function applyTransform(bounds, currentTransform) {
  bounds.x = ct.e + bounds.x * ct.a;
  bounds.y = ct.f + bounds.y * ct.d;
  bounds.width = bounds.width * ct.a;
  bounds.height = bounds.height * ct.d;
}
```

Comment: What is your current hit-detection code?

Comment: I don't have any yet, I will try the mentioned solution though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this really depends on what your question is. You wrote:

> How to get the 2d dimensions of the object being drawn

And you wrote

> for hit testing.

Which do you want. You want the 2d dimensions or you want hit testing?

For the dimensions you'd need to know the size of your shape on your own before being transformed. Then you can get the current transform with [`ctx.currentTransform`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/currentTransform)

Unfortunately `currentTransform` is only supported on Chrome as of August 2019 so you need some kind of polyfill but if you search for ["currentTransform polyfill"](https://www.google.com/search?q=currentTransform+polyfill) there are several out there.

For hit testing you can use [`ctx.isPointInPath`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/isPointInPath)

You define a path. It does not have to be the same as the thing you're drawing though of course it make some sense if it is. Then you can call

```
ctx.isPointInPath(pathToCheck, canvasRelativeX, canvasRelativeY);
```

```js
const ctx = document.querySelector('canvas').getContext('2d');

const path = new Path2D();
const points = [
 [10, 0],
 [20, 0],
 [20, 10],
 [30, 10],
 [30, 20],
 [20, 20],
 [20, 30],
 [10, 30],
 [10, 20],
 [0, 20],
 [0, 10],
 [10, 10],
];
points.forEach(p => path.lineTo(...p));
path.closePath();

let mouseX;
let mouseY;

function render(time) {
  const t = time / 1000;
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);
  ctx.translate(
      150 + Math.sin(t * 0.1) * 100,
       75 + Math.cos(t * 0.2) * 50);
  ctx.rotate(t * 0.3);
  ctx.scale(
       2 + Math.sin(t * 0.4) * 0.5,
       2 + Math.cos(t * 0.5) * 0.5);
       
  const inpath = ctx.isPointInPath(path, mouseX, mouseY);
  ctx.fillStyle = inpath ? 'red' : 'blue';
       
  ctx.fill(path);
  ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);  // reset transform
  
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
}
requestAnimationFrame(render);

ctx.canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', (e) => {
  mouseX = e.offsetX * ctx.canvas.width / ctx.canvas.clientWidth;
  mouseY = e.offsetY * ctx.canvas.height / ctx.canvas.clientHeight;
});
```

```css
canvas { border: 1px solid black; }
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```

Comment: `IsPointInPath` is called when rendering in the view code, but I don't want to mix logic in view code. The view might tell the dimensions of the drawn objects, and controller later checks to see if any collisions occur with those dimensions. What if I want to check two objects being collided, now view code becomes a mess doesn't it.

Comment: What's the difference? You wanted a hit test on the transformed shape. So you either have to save the hit check or you have to save the transform itself. Either way you're going to have to save stuff related to hits in your draw code. Your other option so to do all matrix math yourself and then call `ctx.setTransform(...matrixToComputedElseWhere)`. You can then compute those matrices outside the draw code and use them in both the draw code and hit tests. You can either do the hit tests yourself or `ctx.setTransform(matrixForHitTest); const hit = ctx.isPointInPath(...)` outside your draw code.

Comment: what do you think of my solution with the collision canvas, that way you can actually see the hitboxes too.

Comment: I think using a canvas to check collisions will be slow since you'll have to check 1000s of pixels per shape. Doing collisions is actually a lot of work. Even simple collisions like circle to circle eventually end up needing some kind of spatial partition. Like if you want to collide 100 circles that will require ~5000 collision checks unless you find a way to spatially partition the circles so you don't have to check each circle against every other circle. That's why people use collision libraries since optimizing is a lot of work.

Comment: what if I want to know the object's position at which the point collided with the object?

Comment: I updated my question to reflect the `currentTransform` solution, could you also update your answer to show the usage of `currentTransform` @gman.